# Granularidad en Base de Datos

Tags: sql-server

Necesito información sobre lo que es y como se maneja **Granularidad fina**, especialmente en `SQL Server`. Muchas Gracias

Comment: Hola Javtronic. Este sitio no sustituye a un búscador. Has de investigar por tu cuenta y si en el proceso de implementación o uso tienes problemas, mira [ask] para formular una pregunta válida y de calidad. Un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La granularidad se refiere a que tan fino se quiere que sea un bloqueo. Por ejemplo ¿descea bloquear la tabla completa (**un bloqueo de granularidad gruesa**) o solo decea bloquear una fila especifica (**un bloqueo de granularidad fina)**?.

Segun la documentación de **microsoft** en general de la granularidad dice lo siguente:

El Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine (Motor de base de datos de SQL Server) admite bloqueo multigranular.

Esta función permite que una transacción bloquee diferentes tipos de recursos. Para minimizar el costo del bloqueo, Motor de base de datos bloquea automáticamente los recursos en el nivel apropiado para la tarea.

Los bloqueos de menor granularidad, como es el caso de las filas, aumentan la simultaneidad. Sin embargo, se produce una sobrecarga mayor porque cuantas más filas se bloquean, más bloqueos se deben mantener.

Los bloqueos realizados en una granularidad alta, por ejemplo en tablas, reducen la simultaneidad porque el bloqueo de toda una tabla restringe el acceso de otras transacciones a cualquier parte de la tabla.

Sin embargo, produce una sobrecarga menor debido a que se mantienen menos bloqueos.

Deseas ver mas información [Link](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms189849(v=sql.105).aspx)